# debounce function not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having problem understanding why the below debounce code does not work?

you can see the below code in the following: [**link**](https://codepen.io/shankar094/pen/RwawXMM)

```
`
HTML:

<input type="text" onkeyup="betterFunction(event)"/>

JS:

let newValue;
let counter = 0;
const getData = () => {
    // dummy call to API and get Data
    console.log("Fetching Data ..", newValue,counter++);
}

const debounce = function (fn, d) {
    let timer;
    return function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            fn();
        }, d);
   }
}

const betterFunction = ({target:{value}}) => {
    newValue=value;
    debounce(getData, 2000); // **line 1**. placing this line of code debouncing does not happen
  
    intermediate()  // **line 2**. replacing this line of code with the above line debouncing works
}

const intermediate = debounce(getData, 2000);

`
```

I understand that the debounce function returns another function which acts like a closure in JavaScript but why the above line 1 code does not work but the line 2 code works

Comment: debounce function should wrap the betterFunction call, then on timeout it then calls the betterFunction, your calling betterFunction first then calling the debounce

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`debounce` function returns a function which is never called when you call `debounce` as

```
debounce(getData, 2000);
```

`dobounce` function doesn't needs to return a function. You just need following steps to implement `debounce` function:

1. Check if `timer` is undefined or not. If not, that means there's a timeout that we need to cancel.
2. After that set a new timer by calling `setTimeout()` that calls the given function after specific amount of time.

Also, `timer` should not be a local variable because you don't want it to reset whenever `debounce` function is called.

```js
let counter = 0;
let newValue;
let timer;

const getData = () => {
  console.log("Fetching Data ..", newValue, counter++);
}

const debounce = function(fn, d) {
  if (timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }

  timer = setTimeout(fn, d);
}

const betterFunction = (e) => {
  newValue = e.target.value;
  debounce(getData, 2000);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="betterFunction(event)" />
```

If you don't want to declare `timer` as a global variable and want to return a function from `debounce` function, then you need to call the `debounce` function once initially and whenever `keyup` event fires on the `input` element, you call the function returned from the `debounce` function instead of calling the `debounce` function.

```js
let counter = 0;
let newValue;

const getData = () => {
  console.log('Fetching Data ..', newValue, counter++);
};

const debounce = function(fn, d) {
  let timer;
  
  return function() {
    if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }

    timer = setTimeout(fn, d);
  };
};

const intermediate = debounce(getData, 2000);

const betterFunction = (e) => {
  newValue = e.target.value;
  intermediate();
};
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="betterFunction(event)" />
```

Comment: your explanation was wonderful, it really helped me to better understand how closures work. one thing that i noticed is your answer is that it is not necessary to pass getData and 2000 to intermediate(getData, 2000) inside the betterFunction (in 2nd code snippet).

Comment: _it is not necessary to pass getData and 2000 to intermediate_ - yes of-course, its not necessary and i didn't notice that while answering. Updated the second code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

i hope that what you want :

```
let counter = 0;
// you need to define timer and newValue here first
let timer , newValue;

// defining input as varible for good usage better than usage in html
var input = document.querySelector("#inp");

const getData = () => {
    // increment first better than in console :)
    counter+=1;
    console.log("Fetching Data .." , newValue , counter);

    // as last step clear timer for next timeout
    clearTimeout(timer);
}

// givin value direct to timer directlly worked better than return
const debounce = function (fn, d) {
    timer = setTimeout(fn, d);
}


const betterFunction = () => {
    // newvalue must equal input value
    newValue = input.value;
    // and then calling debounce as last step
    debounce(getData, 2000);
}

// here giving onkeyup event to input for getting values and start working :)
input.onkeyup = betterFunction;
```